# Ruby on Rails: Problems debuggin an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I am having problems in order to debug an app using ruby-debug with RadRails.
I try to install the gem with gem install ruby-debug19 -as I am using Ruby 1.9.1-p249 but I get the following error:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:>gem install ruby-debug19
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug19:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby191/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby191/bin/ruby
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:364:in `try_do': The complier failed 
to genera
te an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:433:in`try_cpp'
        from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:811:in `block in 
have_header'
        from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:670:in`block in 
checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `block (2 levels) 
in postp
one'
        from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:250:in`open'
        from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `block in 
postpone'
        from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:250:in`open'
        from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:272:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:669:in`checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:810:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:15:in`block in '
        from 
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/ruby
_core_source.rb:18:in `call'
        from 
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/ruby
_core_source.rb:18:in`create_makefile_with_core'
        from extconf.rb:20:in `'

Gem files will remain installed in 
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache
19-0.5.11 for inspection.
Results logged to 
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.11/ext/tra
ce_nums/gem_make.out

C:>

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just installed RubyInstaller 1.9.2 and worked

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing... it didn't find `vm_core.h`, so you have to set that path using `-I<path>`.

If I may suggest you something for less pain, use [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) + [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) + [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).

Comment: How then do I use the -I<path>? Where's vm_core.h supposed to be?
I'm kinda newbie with all this..

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I don't really see that many people use Windows for Ruby development.